# How can I set two serials for GRUB

Tags: linux, debian, serial-console

I'm on `debian 10`. I want to show `GRUB` messages based on the configuration in `BIOS` for `serial_com0` and `serial_com1`. I want a general config that worked on my all devices without knowing what the `BIOS` config is.

#### my`/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=ttyS1,115200n8 quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Serial Configuration
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm serial"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

I only see the `GRUB` message on `ttyS0`, but not on `ttyS1`.
I know the `--unit=0` define which serial should show the `GRUB` message, but I don't know how I can set the serial for both `tty`s.